# injecting ui-router resolve to directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

i am using ui-router and there i am resolving some data i want to inject the resolve to my custom directive ,below is code how i am doing

```
 module portal {
           $stateProvider.state('portal', {
        url: '/demo',
        template: tpl.html,
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {

            demoResolve:function(){
                 return 'foo';//here i am returing a promise
        }
    });    

}


module portal.directives{


export class demoDirevtive{

    static $inject =['demoResolve'];
    constructor(demoResolve){
        console.log(demoResolve)
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
        directive.link = (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) => {

        };
        directive.restrict = "EAC";

        return directive;
    }
  }
}
```

but i am getting error of unknown provider

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From reading their code it doesn't seem like it's possible, they have a local variable that they inject into the controller you define on the view, it's not accessible via $inject service as well.

Easiest solution would be to put it on the controller's scope, and then use it in the directive.

You can also create a real service, that will hold all the resolved objects in your application, i.e.:

```
resolve: {
     demoResolve: ['myResolvingService', function(resolver) {
          resolver.myValue = 'Foo';
          return 'Foo';
     }]
```

I know it's not what you were looking for, but it just doesn't look like it's supported.

Comment: seems like angular doesn't play well with ui-router resolve,i mean i dnt think we can inject that well i found a workaround stored in rootscope and access rootscope in directive

Comment: Yep, that's another solution, storing on rootscope is the easiest solution, but I try to avoid it because it can easily get messy, just like saving stuff on the window.

Comment: By design, ui-router resolves are only injectable into the controller and onEnter/onExit callbacks.  They are not globally injectable via $injector.

Comment: @PranayDutta I would put it on the controller's $scope, not the $rootScope.

Answer (score 8):

Here is example how to pass resolve value to directive via controller:

```
        .state('something.edit', {
            url: '/:id',
            template: '<something-edit title="title"></something-edit>',
            controller: function($scope, $title){
                $scope.title = $title;
            },
            resolve: {
                $title: ()=>{
                    return 'Something Edit';
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Tom,
Can you give more information here ? On your example I don't see how you injected resolve $title to directive.

Comment: Its injected via attribute title="title" in template.

Comment: This approach is somewhat cumbersome, but I ended up doing it the same way when switching to "component-like routing". Anyway wish someone could come up with better way so we can ditch the proxy controller.

Answer (score 3):

They added support for this in 2016.

This is the github thread:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2664#issuecomment-204593098

The important part is:

> in 0.2.19 we are adding $resolve to the $scope, allowing you to do "route to component template" style
>
> template: `<my-directive input="$resolve.simpleObj"></my-directive>`,